Showing positivity of atomic measure with integrating against square polynomials

Let $\mu$ be an (signed) atomic measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, by definition, $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{M} c_{i}\delta_{x_{i}}$ for some positive integer $M$. Then for what $M$, is $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}_{d}[x], \int p^{2} \, d\mu\geq 0 \iff \mu\geq 0$? ($\mathbb{R}_{d}[x]$ denotes all real polynomials with $n$ variables and degree at most d)

I think this is true when $M$ is small, essentially by some interpolating argument, but I'm not familiar with algebraic geometry and know the limitations on the number of points I can interpolate a degree polynomial with. Or maybe there are other tricks one can do?
The problem arises from polynomial optimization and may have connections to truncated moment problem.
